# GroovyInterceptable does not work on methods with no arguments

Tags: groovy

A simple code snippet which uses invokeMethod in combination with `GroovyInterceptable`. If the nested `simpleMethod2` has an argument, it works - otherwise not.

I have not found an explanation, so I assume it should work with nested methods without arguments as well?

```
class SimpleFlow implements GroovyInterceptable {

    def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        System.out.println("time before ${name} called: ${new Date()}")

        def calledMethod = SimpleFlow.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
        calledMethod?.invoke(this, args)

        System.out.println("time after ${name} called: ${new Date()}\n")
    }

    void simpleMethod1(){
        System.out.println("simpleMethod1() called")
        simpleMethod2Nested()
    }

    // works well when using an argument
    void simpleMethod2Nested(){
        System.out.println("simpleMethod2Nested")
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def flow = new SimpleFlow()
        flow.simpleMethod1()
    }
}
```

Output without argument:

```
time before simpleMethod1 called: Tue Jun 21 04:16:41 CEST 2011
simpleMethod1() called
simpleMethod2Nested
time after simpleMethod1 called: Tue Jun 21 04:16:41 CEST 2011`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet sure if it's a bug or a feature [:)](http://www.spatiallyrelevant.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/bug-feature.jpg) (most probably a bug because method with args do work as expected - please do raise a bug in groovy jira). Meanwhile you can fix it by adding a variable `self` which references to `this` and use it to call the nested method:

```
class SimpleFlow implements GroovyInterceptable {

def self = this

def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
    // same as original
}

void simpleMethod1(){
    System.out.println("simpleMethod1() called")
    self.simpleMethod2Nested() // note the use of self
}

// works well when using an argument
void simpleMethod2Nested(){
    System.out.println("simpleMethod2Nested")
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    def flow = new SimpleFlow()
    flow.simpleMethod1()
}

}
```

Output:

```
time before simpleMethod1 called: Tue Jun 21 13:32:44 GMT+08:00 2011
simpleMethod1() called
time before simpleMethod2Nested called: Tue Jun 21 13:32:44 GMT+08:00 2011
simpleMethod2Nested
time after simpleMethod2Nested called: Tue Jun 21 13:32:44 GMT+08:00 2011
time after simpleMethod1 called: Tue Jun 21 13:32:44 GMT+08:00 2011
```

Comment: Great, it's really amazing how fast this was answered, if I could, I would add points for velocity :) I just do not understand why just `this` does not work - why do I have to assign `this` to `self`? Btw. this error is Groovy 1.8.0 only, lower versions works correctly. I will file a bug this evening.

Comment: @Ice09 I think that just `this` doesn't not work because compiler adds it to any method invocation anyway. But with `self` some different mechanism must be triggering..

Comment: Thought of this as well, certainly makes sense. However, I would have never tried this in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: In some testing I did it looked a bit like Groovy might be trying to resolve it as a property not a method if it has no args, but that seems awfully odd